# DATEADD error when use French language?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a SP which needs to calculate some date & time. It works fine when the language is set as English. However, when it is French, it has this error:

La conversion d'un type de données varchar en type de données datetime a créé une valeur hors limites.

Which means datetime overflow based on translation.

The query is similar to:

```
SET LANGUAGE  'French'

DECLARE @StartPastDays INT
SET @StartPastDays = 1;

DECLARE @PastDays INT
SET @PastDays = 30;

PRINT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),111)
PRINT CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE(),111)
PRINT DATEADD(day, -(@PastDays+@StartPastDays-1), CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),111) )
PRINT DATEADD(day, -(@PastDays+@StartPastDays-1), CAST('2013-07-23' AS DATE))
```

If I run it, the result is:

Le paramètre de langue est passé à Français.

2013/07/23

2013-07-23

Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 16
La conversion d'un type de données varchar en type de données datetime a créé une valeur hors limites.

2013-06-23

the error happens at:
PRINT DATEADD(day, -(@PastDays+@StartPastDays-1), CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),111) )

Anyone knows why?

Comment: Dear, why you convert in varchar(10) your getdate when dateadd wants datetime / smalldatetime as third parameter?

Comment: Treating date(times) as strings is almost always the source of such errors. If you want to remove the time portion from a datetime, there are plenty of solutions that don't require conversion to `varchar`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this

```
SET LANGUAGE  FRENCH
SET DATEFORMAT ymd
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

`DATEADD` requires a Date, so just pass `GETDATE()` or `CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)`

```
SET LANGUAGE  'French'

DECLARE @StartPastDays INT
SET @StartPastDays = 1;

DECLARE @PastDays INT
SET @PastDays = 30;

PRINT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),111)
PRINT CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE(),111)
PRINT DATEADD(day, -(@PastDays+@StartPastDays-1), CAST(GETDATE() AS Date))
PRINT DATEADD(day, -(@PastDays+@StartPastDays-1), CAST('2013-07-23' AS DATE))
```